# Pyspark parallel ml.KMeans overwrite each other's K

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, concurrency, pyspark, k-means

I followed this post to run KMeans in parallel. I used Python 2.7 and Spark 2.0.2 on EMR.

[How to run multiple jobs in one Sparkcontext from separate threads in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214474/how-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-one-sparkcontext-from-separate-threads-in-pyspark)

As quoted in the post, jobs submitted from different processes should not affect each other.

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads. By “job”, in this section, we mean a Spark action (e.g. save, collect) and any tasks that need to run to evaluate that action. Spark’s scheduler is fully thread-safe and supports this use case to enable applications that serve multiple requests (e.g. queries for multiple users)."
>   http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html

However the resulting model's clusters number K is different from what was passed in.

Code:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
import random
random.seed(1)

group_size = 30
n_groups = 20

n_samples= n_groups * group_size
n_features=2
n_centers=4

xs, ys = make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=n_features, centers=n_centers, cluster_std=1.0, center_box=(-10.0, 10.0), shuffle=True, random_state=None)
x_groups = []
for i in range(n_groups):
    x_groups.append(xs[i*group_size: (i+1)*group_size])


def do_kmean(xs):
    data = []
    for x in xs:
        data.append((Vectors.dense(x.tolist()),) )
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])

    num_clusters = random.randint(5,10)
    kmeans = KMeans(k=num_clusters, maxIter=1, seed=1, featuresCol="features", predictionCol="prediction")
    model = kmeans.fit(df)
    return [num_clusters, kmeans.getK()]

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
tpool = ThreadPool(processes=8)

result = tpool.map(do_kmean, x_groups)
```

Result: (Input K vs what KMeans actually used)

```
[[5, 9],
 [8, 9],
 [6, 8],
 [10, 9],
 [7, 9],
 [9, 9],
 [7, 9],
 [9, 9],
 [5, 5],
 [5, 9],
 [9, 7],
 [9, 9],
 [5, 7],
 [10, 5],
 [7, 7],
 [7, 7],
 [6, 6],
 [10, 10],
 [10, 10],
 [5, 5]]
```

It seems Spark is not thread/process safe and accessing other process's copy of the K. Could any of the Spark configuration cause this problem or is this a Spark bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug for Spark 2.0.2 and 2.1.0. I was able to replicate the bug on my local machine with above two versions. The bug is fixed for Spark 2.1.1.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19348