# Spark Scala, train many models concurrently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

I have a `train` and `test` dataset with features, and several thousand `customerId` values.
My goal is to concurrently train one binary `xgboost` classifier per `customerId` in Spark.

I'm essentially trying to do what the poster in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214474/how-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-one-sparkcontext-from-separate-threads-in-pyspark/32285527) is asking about, but in Scala instead of PySpark.
I understand from reading around that the answer is given in the following [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html), but I'm unsure how to implement it.
The Job Scheduling documentation for Spark tells me that I need to initiate the training of each model from separate threads.

So far my code looks something like this:

```
// Data
val train: DataFrame = ...
val test: DataFrame = ...

// Model
val xgbClassifier: XGBoostClassifier = ...

// List of unique customerId's
val customers: List[Int] = ...

// Function for training and predicting for a given customer
def trainAndPredict(customer: Int): DataFrame = {
  val train_subset = train.filter($"customerId" === customer)
  val test_subset = test.filter($"customerId" === customer)
  ...
}

// Recursively train and predict for all customers
@tailrec
final def recTrainAndPredict(customers: List[Int], acc: DataFrame): DataFrame = customers match {
  case Nil => acc
  case x :: xs => recTrainAndPredict(xs, acc.union(trainAndPredict(x)))
}

val result = recTrainAndPredict(customers, spark.emptyDataFrame)
```

The code runs, but I'm guessing it's wasting a lot of time by spreading small datasets across different nodes.
How would I go about getting different calls of `trainAndPredict` to be run concurrently without sacrificing time by distributing the job across different nodes?

Comment: Building one model for each customer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @hadooper See this post for an outline of the underlying motivation:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391271/xgboost-boosted-decision-trees-representing-categorical-id-numbers-as-continu